# Using babel traverse to to get comments in AST

Tags: babeljs, babel-babylon

How do I traverse comments with `babelTraverse`?

```
babelTraverse(nodes, {
  CommentBlock: (path) => {
    console.log(path)
  },
  CommentLine: (path) => { 
    console.log(path)
  }
})
```

> Error: You gave us a visitor for the node type CommentBlock but it's not a valid type

Answer (score 3):

The `CommentBlock` and `CommentLine` are not part of the `program.body` in the `ast` returned by the babel parser. These comment types live outside of the program body. I am assuming that is why we get the Type error when we add `CommentLine` and `CommentBlock`.

The comments for a node can be accessed, using `traverse`, as follows:

```
traverse(ast, {
  ClassDeclaration(path) {
    console.log(path.node.leadingComments);
    console.log(path.node.trailingComments);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can't traverse that way but you can access comments with:

`nodes.comments`